# failed to load 'libmain.so' !! your hardware does not support this application

Tags: unity-game-engine

Failed to load 'libmain.so' !! your hardware does not support this application !!!! this is the error that I'm getting while I run the app on my phone.

mobile : motoG5 [see screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjNhf.jpg)

there was no problem in compiling, building successfully completes with zero error. the issue I'm getting is when I launch this android app on my phone I'm getting this failure.[check the screenshot] how to fix this guys ?? please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check which architecture version supports you device and build apk according to it. you can find current version at PlayerSettings > Other Settings > Target Architectures.

Answer (score 0):

copy so, jnilibs/armeabi-v7a to libs/armeabi-v7a
[image]

Comment: gradel plugin: 7.0.1
Android Studio: Chipmunk 2021.2.1

Comment: ```
val uri = requireContext().applicationInfo.nativeLibraryDir
      LogUtils.e("----> unityunity", uri)
      val file = File(uri)
      if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory) {
        for (f in file.listFiles()) {
          LogUtils.e("----> unityunity", f.absolutePath)
        }
      }
```